# How do you make a water portal in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I was recently on a server with these things that looked like portals except with water, it was before the aether mod. I was wondering, how do you build them?

I don't want the Aether or Portal mods.

Comment: What did the portals do? Any details to narrow down the list of possible mods would be helpful.

Comment: This is confusing... Do you have a screenshot? Can you describe the portal a bit better? How does it look like exactly? What does it do? In this case a `Place some dirt blocks in a oval, place water source blocks at the inner top.` answer would be valid but I guess that's not what you are after. I've removed [tag:portal] because it's used for the Portal game.

Comment: Do you just want a [portal (shape) made with water](http://i.imgur.com/yA7kK.png)?

Comment: It probably was the Aether mod, except it was probably a development build.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [bukkit plugin called "Creative Gates"](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tp-creative-gates-v1-3-2-portalize-anything-no-chat-commands-1317.22732/)

Answer (score 2):

The old ServerPort plugin, which allowed traveling beetween servers, had one of these. Sadly, the author has abandoned the Bukkit version of his plugin, and there are only Nether Gates now.
http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/inactive-tp-server-port-v377-teleport-between-servers-1000.777/

You can see the portal here, to check if it's the one you meant:

Answer (score 1):

It is only a skin pack, you can edit it yourself or download them online

Comment: The appearance of the portal surface cannot be altered by a texture pack in stock Minecraft; the animated portal texture is created by Minecraft itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Multiverse portals](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-portals/) which allow you to create portals out of water and other materials to travel to other worlds. It requires [Multiverse](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-core/).

Here is a video demonstrating how to use the plugin

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla Minecraft, creating this effect is simple. First, make your portal. (Do this any way you would like.) Next, put pressure plates in front of it. Lastly, put command blocks under the pressure plates with a command such as

> /tp @p ~ ~ ~.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you can't make water portals in vanilla minecraft. If you want to, though, you can always get a bukkit server and get the water portal plugin.

Comment: If you are referring to a different mod than those listed in the other answers, be more specific (perhaps by providing a link or something). If you are referring to the mods already listed, this answer is not very helpful unless you provide some information that the other answers do not. As it stands, this answer is not useful and needs improvement.